# How to format Send-MailMessage body contents

Tags: powershell, email

I am working on a script that will ping a list of workstations and return add them to an array if they are offline. After they are added to an array the script then sends an email with the list of offline workstations. Here is the script so far

```
$list = Get-Content "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop\workstations.txt"
ForEach ($_ in $list) { 
$test = Test-Connection -BufferSize 32 -Count 1 -ComputerName $_ -Quiet
IF ($test -match "false") {
$offlinelist += ($_)
}
}
Send-MailMessage -To "me <me@me.com>" -From "you <you@you.com>" -Subject "Offline Workstations" -SmtpServer "smtp.me.com" -body "These workstations are offline: <br> $offlinelist" -BodyAsHtml
```

In its current form the code will send an email with a output that looks like this:

> These workstations are offline:
>   test1test2

What I need it to look like is this:

> These workstations are offline:
>   test1
>   test2

I know there is a way to do it with possibly `New-Object` cmdlet or possibly the `Format-Table` cmdlet. I am just not sure how to go about structuring the code. I have found several examples, but I am not able to make it work with the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet. Also, is it possible to stylize the body of the email with a different color font or face? Any help or example would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this in the future, I was able to solve my problem by adding a `<br>` after the workstation name in the array:

`$offlinelist += "$_ <br>"`

This seems to work because of the `BodyAsHtml` attribute in the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet. I am not sure if this is the *correct* way syntax wise, but it is working for me without error. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The above answer likely works, but if you want to keep it as a raw string you can also use windows newlines

```
$offlinelist += "$_ `n`r"
```